# My code runs, but the if statements are not printing their contents when I compare contents of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a simple mastermind game where a 4 digit number will be randomly selected by the computer and the user inputs a number over and over again until the correct number is found. I am trying to do this by passing the guessed number and the random number to their own separate arrays and then comparing them, position by position to see if they are similar. If two numbers are in the exact same spot

Example:

`if guessArray[0] == numsArray[0]` then the computer will print a `*`.

If two numbers are present but not in the exact same spot (eg. you made a guess of `2056` but the actual number is `1203`) then one `+` should be printed. This cycle repeats until the number is guessed.

I've already asked a friend in person what the problem was and he couldn't figure it out. He knows the most code out of my friends so this was my next place to go.

Here is the full project. I did not write the `ConvertInt2Array` method. I found it on the internet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class Mastermind {
    public static Random numGen = new Random();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int random = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int numArray[] = new int[4];
        int guessArray[] = new int[4];
        boolean isGuessed = false;
        //Generate Random Number
        for(x=0; x<=3; x++) {
            int rand = Math.abs(numGen.nextInt());//Get the absolute value
            random = (rand % 999 + 1);
            numArray[x] = random;
            number+=random;
        }
        while(isGuessed == false){
            System.out.println("Guess a four digit random number");
            guess = Input.nextInt();
            guessArray = convertInt2Array(guess);
            for(y=0; y<=3; y++) {
                if(numArray[y] == guessArray[y]) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if(Arrays.equals(numArray, y, y, guessArray, 0, guessArray.length) == true) {
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
                else {
                }
                if(guess==number) {
                    isGuessed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You guessed it correctly!");
    }
    public static int[] convertInt2Array(int guess)  {
        String temp = Integer.toString(guess);
        String temp2;
        int temp3;
        int [] gArray = new int[temp.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++) {
            if (i!=temp.length()) {
                temp2 = temp.substring(i, i+1);
            } else {
                temp2 = temp.substring(i);
            }
            temp3 =  Integer.parseInt(temp2);    
           gArray[i] = temp3;
        }
        return gArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip #1, when comparing booleans you can simply do `while (!isGuessed) { ...}` which is the same as `while (isGuessed == false) { ... }` or your `if (Arrays.equals...)` you can safely remove the `== true` part. This makes your code more readable and safer (to typos)

Comment: `Arrays.equals(numArray, y, y, guessArray, 0, guessArray.length)` - The documentation states, "Two arrays are considered equal if the number of elements covered by each range is the same...", which is **not** the case for this line of code, so it will always return `false`.

Comment: Ah I see, so what would be the best way to see if two arrays contain the same integers, but not in the exact same spots?

Comment: @ScottJanssen You can sort both arrays and then compare them with `Arrays#equals`.

Comment: array#equals? Could you link the oracle page to the method you are referring to?

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug, but your line `random = (rand % 999 + 1)` is usually going to return a 3 digit number. Did you want this to return a 4 digit number instead?

Comment: He means `Arrays.equals(...)` but here in Stack Overflow we tend to use the `#` to denote it's a method when in a comment.

Comment: @broAhmed I want to return a 4 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one issue here, but here's a potential problem:

```
int rand = Math.abs(numGen.nextInt()); // Get the absolute value
random = (rand % 999 + 1);
```

This will usually result in `random` being a three-digit number. You mentioned you want this to be a four-digit number. [`Random.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) can return any of the possible 2<sup>32</sup> integer numbers (from -2147483648 to 2147483647). To fix this, use a different `Random.nextInt` and specify your bounds:

```
int lowerBound = 1000;
int upperBound = 10000;
random = numGen.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound;
```

Let's break this down: `numGen.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound)` evaluates to `numGen.nextInt(9000)`, which will return a number between 0 (inclusive) and 9000 (exclusive), i.e. anything in the range 0-8999. You then add the lower bound of 1000 to ensure that `random` will be at least 1000 and up to 9999.

See the documentation for [`Random.nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right track.